# How to open a json.gz file and return to dictionary in Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have downloaded a compressed json file and want to open it as a dictionary.

I used `json.load` but the data type still gives me a `string`.
I want to extract a keyword list from the json file. Is there a way I can do it even though my data is a string?
Here is my code:

```py
import gzip
import json
with gzip.open("19.04_association_data.json.gz", "r") as f:

 data = f.read()
with open('association.json', 'w') as json_file:  
     json.dump(data.decode('utf-8'), json_file)

with open("association.json", "r") as read_it: 
     association_data = json.load(read_it) 



print(type(association_data))

#The actual output is 'str' but I expect it is 'dic'
```

Answer (score 4):

In the first `with` block you already got the uncompressed string, no need to open it a second time.

```
import gzip
import json

with gzip.open("19.04_association_data.json.gz", "r") as f:
   data = f.read()
   j = json.loads (data.decode('utf-8'))
   print (type(j))
```

Answer (score 2):

Open the file using the `gzip` package from the standard library ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html)), then read it directly into `json.loads()`:

```
import gzip
import json    

with gzip.open("19.04_association_data.json.gz", "rb") as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read(), encoding="utf-8")
```

Comment: i dump the data again because once I ran your code above, it said "json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 2350)". I was thinking that because my gz file has mutiple json objects, so I dump them all in one file.

Comment: @CarolineCheng I think you have a list in there which is not supported by json.

Answer (score 0):

To read from a `json.gz`, you can use the following snippet:

```
import json
import gzip

with gzip.open("file_path_to_read", "rt") as f:
        expected_dict = json.load(f)
```

The result is of type `dict`.

In case if you want to write to a `json.gz`, you can use the following snippet:

```
import json
import gzip

with gzip.open("file_path_to_write", "wt") as f:
        json.dump(expected_dict, f)
```